# Updating two objects of state array simultaneously in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here are objects of state array:

```
 const [items, setItems] = useState([
   {
    id: 1,
    completed: true
   },
   {
    key: 2,
    complete: true
   },
   {
    key: 3,
    complete: true
   }
    ])
```

by one submitting I want to add new object and change pervious object's property completed to false simultaneously, in short I want to get this result:

```
  const [items, setItems] = useState([
   {
    id: 1,
    completed: true
   },
   {
    key: 2,
    complete: true
   },
   {
    key: 3,
    complete: false
   },
   {
    key: 4,
    complete: true
   }
    ])
```

I understand how to add new object:

```
  const handleSubmit = e => {
    setItems([
      ...items,
      {
        key: 4,
        complete: true
      },
    ]);
  }
```

But as I mentioned above is it possible to update previous object as well by one submitting? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Prepare the new object and then pass it to `setItems()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function updateItems(newItem, completedId){
    setItems(prevItems =>{
        const result = prevItems.map(item =>{
            if(item.id !== completedId) 
                return item

            return {...item, complete : true}
        })

        return result.concat(newItem)
    })
}
```

For an array of ids to check as complete you could do

`if(completedIds.includes(item.id)`

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can use this, copy the state, and then select last object complete and change it. after that u can setItems()

```
const handleSubmit = e => {
     const tempItems = [...items];
     tempItems[items.length - 1].complete = false;
     setItems([...tempItems,{key: 4,complete: true}]);
}
```

instead of writing a manual key

```
setItems([...tempItems, {key:items.length + 1, complete:true}])
```